# The hello world of sprox with pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, sprox

I've tried to build the simplest possible form in [Sprox](http://sprox.org) using pyramid.

```
# model.py
class Allocation:
    # some fields ...
class SproxForm(AddRecordForm):
    __model__ = Allocation

sprox_form = SproxForm(DBSession)
```

---

```
# views.py
def sprox_form(request):
    return {'f':sprox_form,'kw':{}}
```

---

```
<html>
<body>
<div tal:content="structure f(kw)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But it just prints out `{'kw': {}, 'f': }` The [forms tutorial](http://sprox.org/tutorials/form.html) is written using TurboGears2 and I am unable to translate it to pyramid, because I am new to pyramid.

So could someone tell me what am I doing wrong, or show me a short (but complete) example, which uses pyramid?

Comment: Solved, but I still have a related problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425584/hello-world-of-sprox-with-pyramid-part-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your form is named `sprox_form` and your view is named `sprox_form`. This ambiguity is gonna be a bad idea. Other than that I can't see anything suspicious, assuming your chameleon syntax is correct. If you were using mako it'd be simply `${f(kw)}` although instead of `f` I might suggest using the name `widget` or `form`, and instead of `kw` maybe `value` or `form_input`.

Comment: Thanks, the main problem was the name ambiguity.